# The distribution of amajor over standard Young tableaux?

Tags: co.combinatorics, young-tableaux

Given a standard Young tableau $T$, $i$ is called an ascent of $T$ if $i+1$ is in a higher row than $i$, and amajor$(T)$ is defined to be the sum of ascents of $T$. For the distribution of the amajor indices over standard Young tableaux of skew shapes $\lambda/\mu$, Krattenthaler (Equation (6.1) in Manuscripta Mathematica volume 63, 129–155(1989)) gave a determinantal expression. Is there a any simplification of that result for the special case $\mu=0$, like the well-known $q-$hook length formula which gives the distribution of the major indices over standard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$? And can anyone give some idea about proving Krattenthaler's result via symmetric functions?

Comment: For $\lambda=(3,1,1)$ we get the generating function $1+q^2+2q^3+q^4+q^6$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. This doesn't augur well for an analogue of the $q$-hook formula.